Can I dispose of my older passports?
I have three expired and one recently renewed valid passport.
Should I preserve my older passports, or can I throw them away in the trash can?

I am trying to declutter my life but disposing of old passports is very far down my list of things to go.  They are not big, you won't free up much space.

You don't say where your passports are issued and this is important for the answer.
In a lot of countries, you are expected to return your passport to the government service that issues them, after the passport expires or when you get a new one. They may let you to keep the old one if you need it for a compelling reason (e.g. a visa that is imprinted there and is still valid) or, in other places, for any reason (e.g. a sentiment), but the rule still holds.
Besides of the above reason, you may need (in the future) to prove that you traveled here or there or that you were issued a visa for some country. E.g. a lot of countries will let you in with no other formailities if you have a valid OR EVEN EXPIRED visa for a particular other country. Schengen and USA visas are rather useful in this regard.

The USA sends your old ones back. Good memories of trips. I’d never dispose of them…

The UK also sends the old ones back to you along with the new one when you renew them (doesn't need requesting, they just do). But they chop the corners off the two covers and personal information page to make sure it can't be used again.

@TomCarpenter The US also mutilates the old one so it can’t be reused. The ones I’ve seen returned had a pair of holes punched all the way through (covers and all) about 1/4 of the way down from the top.

When renewing my German passport I was offered to keep the old one.  They mutilated it a bit (they cut a corner away).  I guess it is to prevent the blank pages to be reused for a forgery.

similar in the Netherlands @FlorianF, here they punch 4 big holes in the corners. Also makes it clearly visible when presenting the old passport that it's no longer valid.

Brazil incentives citizens to return their expired passports by doubling the tax to obtain a new passport. As of Oct 2024 the passport renew tax is R$257 (~US$50) and is doubled if you ever had a passport but don't return it.

The idea of punching holes (US) or corner cutting (UK) is to damage the Machine Readable Zone on the biodata page. This stops an automated kiosk or very inattentive immigrations agent's computer from accepting it.

@user71659 Punching holes is way older than the whole machine reading thing

@user71659 An automated kiosk will very quickly find out the passport is expired! No need to punch holes... :-)

@Johnnyjanko Not all invalidated passports are expired. It's obviously a good practice to replace passports before they expire, so there's an overlap of validity periods. Another scenario is a passport is reported lost but later recovered and sent in for invalidation, or simply the passport is replaced because the pages are full (e.g. the US no longer adds pages).

@user71659 Yes, but if that passport is still valid an one is permitted to keep it, I see no reason why it shouldn't be used (before its expiration date). If that country doesn't allow multiple passports, then yes, they will somehow damage it to make it unusable.

You can dispose of expired passports as you wish, but you might want to review this question and its answers before you do so — there are good reasons to keep them.
If you do discard expired passports, they should be shredded. I would not discard a passport that is still valid.

Even if not valid, it contains a lot of information which could be used for identity theft. Do not trust throw away an intact passport. Shred it or somehow make sure at least the whole bio page (including the machine readable zone at the bottom) is made completely and definitively illegible. If the passport contains a chip, make sure it is destroyed as well.

If you discard (or lose) a still valid passport it is very likely you need to report it lost or stolen at the police and use the paperwork from that when you apply for a new passport.

There are some cases that an old passport can be used as ID (not for travelling but e.g. the UK government recently introduced photo-ID for voting and you can use an expired passport if it's still recognisably you), so if you have mislaid your current passport or had to send it away for a visa application, it might be useful.

Another use case where old passports can be useful:
When converting a foreign driver's license to a Japanese driver's license, you are required to prove that, after the foreign license was issued, you spent at least three months in the issuing country.
The goal, as I understand it, is to prevent people from going to countries where driver's licenses are easily obtained without testing or training in order to circumvent the Japanese driver training regime.
Presenting a stack of old passports is the most common way of demonstrating this. It's officially recommended, in fact, to bring your expired passports.
There are more and more situations where travelers do not receive a stamp in their passport when entering or exiting a country: it's an interesting question as to when this practice of using old passports to show residency will end. As for now, it's still commonly used.

I keep mine. On visa applications or even arrival cards, some countries ask for countries visited in the last ‘X’ years, and having the stamps to flip through is a great reminder.
I’ve also had to provide this information for other official purposes.
Of course you may need to keep (and bring) an expired passport if it contains a visa that is still valid.
Also a reminder of places visited along with images of your aging countenance.
P.S. This should be obvious, but store the valid passport in a different place than the historic ones. Grabbing an expired passport and not noticing it until you got to document checking at the airport could be disastrous.
